# How to Post on users wall from my app

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm not sure if this is the right title, but this is what i want to happen.

User subscribes to my app.
When i post on wall in my page, the user who has subscribed to the app, to receive my post on his wall.

Basically this is wat i want to happen, somehow to attach page to an app, and every time i post something to my wall , the subscribed users to have it on their wall.

Comment: Now that Facebook is deprecating the offline access, I'm not sure if this is even still possible unless your users keep coming back to your app to refresh the access token.

Comment: It's fine as long as he gets the long access token which last for two months and just every time they go into the app if the token has or is about to run out then capture the token and store a new long access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you correct, what you want is this to happen: You post something on your FB page. The same message then gets posted to a user's stream?

For this you'll have to use `graph.facebook.com/{your_page}/feed` to recognize when something has been posted on your Page. You can retrieve the post using its ID to ensure you are the poster. When you find a post, you can then write it to a user's wall by making a POST to `graph.facebook.com/{user's_profile_id}/feed`.

You will need to get `publish_stream` permission from users. Also, since `offline_access` has been deprecated, an long issue auth token is only valid for 60 days, thus you will need to renew auth tokens atleast once per 60 days.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

A better system would be for you to not directly post on your page's feed. Instead, build a UI where you enter your message, which then posts the message to your Page, as well as to the stream of your users / subscribers.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want to do..But the way you are suggesting, isn't the user only going to get posts on his wall if he visit the app page ?

Comment: No, he can receive it even if he doesn't visit the page. You simply need to store his auth token in a db and you can then use it to write to his wall even in the user's absence. However, like I mentioned, the token will only be valid for 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

What I've understand is that you want to update a post on your page and users should also be able to see them in their news feed..?? If yes then You can use [**Facebook Graph Api**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to **update status** of your page and the users will able to see that in their **news feed**.

To update page status, you need **extended permissions** like `publish_stream`.

Here's a **full tutorial**:

**http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/update-facebook-page-status-automatically/**

Hope this helps.